# Vega-lite chart fails when field linked in lookup used in legend

Tags: vega-lite

Why does this Vega-lite code fail to display a chart? It uses a transform lookup to join tables and one of the fields from the second table is used in the legend.

[Vega Editor Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zAhcHsUgN1gBsBXAUwGcUwBtMLHHYSAcwCcB7YgByoEYAaKF1Kty7AHZVIAQUKxJAX370GGJm049UAoSLGTUkAOKl2rZqUhKVqtCw7c+gyMNESpAMValoV5bex1By0wACZnV30pAGV4UjxLawC1e00qcN03AygAOQBLAGMAaz8bVSC01AyXPXdDAHU8wkJS5IgKxyqI2uzIAGF2QkT-No6QgGZurKkAJUKSpNHUzrBJzKjDABV2AFsrMuwAXUXIeFZ5cgAzMz3UahVQBkhCdnYilZrpkexIS45btAHKBwRBUdAYIG4AgkChUe5tFLiWA7SyGWTySDOAD6YmIrAKqLQUFgFj4AAZnAUEKRmGYAJ58ACsCkWCKYSJRUm2e2xuPxhPQkBJhIA7JTqbTWAzUONmaylhzCZAvD5MVAcZx+WDiaTtGKoFS4pLpWARXLIWBjt8cJAiqQTZBFZigb88qRCNBKHdIBq8QSAHTCtU+vkBw00+mQQ5lBQqeVMKmEArEORxKQg4g7f2RCQAagA5GB87mM1nffz-eHjcHYF6oEMLOJfPGhcw2DTqVQytQmOwQpByJng5c3R6pOWA0HnLWpPB2Ig5KSFIdBGVllwAEYm6inedEKf1mmkJvBiekSsSyPHLArrCQHawVglQwbx-O3DHgrsaB5cTMMEqJAAAeYKuu6viGGeF5GpGzjwHSwhSGYP5Ii08qQCaTAjuBs57oulhwQhSoAI7EPI8B5IgFEJK0GCQF+LysABTzYWOhgNsevjWrgFHwEMUgALJ0mAAAyR4ntxh6NhBdhmG64jwLhPCUoMmbiHW4yxtgWlgLGChAA)

```
{
  "data": {    
          "values": [ 
            {"group": 1, "person": "Alan"},
            {"group": 1, "person": "George"},
            {"group": 1, "person": "Fred"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Steve"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Nick"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Will"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Cole"},
            {"group": 3, "person": "Rick"},
            {"group": 3, "person": "Tom"}
          ]},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "person",
      "from": {
        "data": {    
          "values": [
              {"name": "Alan", "_source": { "age": 10, "category": 15}},
              {"name": "Tom", "_source": { "age": 7, "category": 35}},
              {"name": "Fred", "_source": { "age": 17, "category": 75}}
          ]},
        "key": "name",
        "fields": ["_source.age", "_source.category"]
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.person+' '+datum._source.category", "as": "legend"},
    {"aggregate": 
      [{"op": "sum", "field": "_source.age", "as": "totalage"}], 
      "groupby": ["totalage", "legend", "_source.category"]}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "_source.category", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "totalage", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "legend",
      "title": "My Legend",
      "legend": {"orient": "top", "columns": 3}
    }
  }
}
```

But this Vega-lite code succeeds in displaying a chart? It uses a transform lookup to join tables and none of the fields from the second table are used in the legend.

[Vega Editor Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zAhcHsUgN1gBsBXAUwGcUwBtMLHHYSAcwCcB7YgByoEYAaKF1Kty7AHZVIAQUKxJAX370GGJm049UAoSLGTUkAOKl2rZqUhKVqtCw7c+gyMNESpAMValoV5bex1By0wACZnV30pAGV4UjxLawC1e00qcN03AygAOQBLAGMAaz8bVSC01AyXPXdDAHU8wkJS5IgKxyqI2uzIAGF2QkT-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)

```
{
  "data": {    
          "values": [ 
            {"group": 1, "person": "Alan"},
            {"group": 1, "person": "George"},
            {"group": 1, "person": "Fred"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Steve"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Nick"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Will"},
            {"group": 2, "person": "Cole"},
            {"group": 3, "person": "Rick"},
            {"group": 3, "person": "Tom"}
          ]},
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "person",
      "from": {
        "data": {    
          "values": [
              {"name": "Alan", "_source": { "age": 10, "category": 15}},
              {"name": "Tom", "_source": { "age": 7, "category": 35}},
              {"name": "Fred", "_source": { "age": 17, "category": 75}}
          ]},
        "key": "name",
        "fields": ["_source.age", "_source.category"]
      }
    },
    {"calculate": "datum.person+' '+datum.group", "as": "legend"},
    {"aggregate": 
      [{"op": "sum", "field": "_source.age", "as": "totalage"}], 
      "groupby": ["totalage", "legend", "_source.category"]}
  ],
  "mark": "bar",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "_source.category", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "totalage", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "field": "legend",
      "title": "My Legend",
      "legend": {"orient": "top", "columns": 3}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the line

```
{"calculate": "datum.person+' '+datum._source.category", "as": "legend"}
```

This says to look for the `category` attribute of `datum._source`. But your data does not have a column named `"_source"`, it has a column named `"_source.category"`.

To fix it, you can reference the column like this:

```
{"calculate": "datum.person+' '+datum['_source.category']", "as": "legend"}
```

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zAhcHsUgN1gBsBXAUwGcUwBtMLHHYSAcwCcB7YgByoEYAaKF1Kty7AHZVIAQUKxJAX370GGJm049UAoSLGTUkAOKl2rZqUhKVqtCw7c+gyMNESpAMValoV5bex1By0wACZnV30pAGV4UjxLawC1e00qcN03AygAOQBLAGMAaz8bVSC01AyXPXdDAHU8wkJS5IgKxyqI2uzIAGF2QkT-No6QgGZurKkAJUKSpNHUzrBJzKjDABV2AFsrMuwAXUXIeFZ5cgAzMz3UahVQBkhCdnYilZrpkexIS45btAHKBwRBUdAYIG4AgkChUe5tFLiWA7SyGWTySDOAD6YmIrAKqLQUFgFj4AAZnAUEKRmGYAJ58ACsCkWCKYSJRUm2e2xuPxhPQkBJhIA7JTqbTWAzUONmaylhzCZAvD5MVAcZx+WDiaTtGKoFS4pLpWARXLIWBjt8cJAiqQTZBFZigb88qRCNBKHdIBq8QSAHTCtU+vkBw00+mQQ5lBQqeVMKmEArEORxKQg4g7f2RCQAagA5GB87mMztqPnffz-eHjfnDsHYF6oEMLOJfPGhcw2DTqVQytQmOwQpByJng5c3R6pJWA0HnI2pPB2Ig5KSFIdBGVllwAEYm6inZdEOfNmmkNvBmekasSyPHLAbrCQHawVglQw71-O3DngrsaB5OIzBgiokAAB5gq67q+IYV43kakbOPAdLCFIZgAUiLTypAJpMBO0GLkeq6WEhKFKgAjsQ8jwHkiA0QkrQYJAf4vKwIFPPhU6GC256+NauA0fAQxSAAsnSYAADJnhe-Gnq2MF2GYbriPAhE8JSgyZuITbjLG2B6WAsYKEAA)

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it. Can you explain why I need to use the square brackets for a field from the joined table and not a field from the original table? Here "datum['_source.category']" is from the joined table and "datum._source.test" is from the original data table. This was not represented in my original example.

    {"calculate": "datum['_source.category']+' '+datum._source.test", "as": "legend"},

Comment: when you use the lookup transform with ``fields: ['_source.name']``, it creates a field named ``"_source.name"``, not a field named ``"_source"`` with an attribute ``"name"``.